# Create ViewHelper in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony-2.1

How to create a ViewHelper in Symfony 2. I read whole the documentation but it doesn't describe any term like that. It just has autoloading and service.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by "Create a ViewHelper" ? If you want to add custom functions/filter/etc to twig, read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: ViewHelper is a way to call a helper function in views (templates). I don't know what it is called in Symfony2 but Zend call it "viewHelper". By the way, I don't use Twig but PHP.

Comment: You can extend twig to create twig filters and functions. Please see the official twig documentation http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Answer (score 4):

You just have to create a class that implements your helper function and extends

```
Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\Helper
```

like this:

```
namespace Acme\Foo\Helper;


use Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\Helper;

class MyViewHelper extends Helper {

    public function helpMe() {
       // do something
       return $value;
    }

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
    public function getName() {
         return "anyCanonicalServiceName";
    }
}
```

Then you have to promote your helper as a service with a special tag in e.g.

```
Resources/config/services.yml


services:
        your_service_name:
        class: Acme\Foo\Helper\MyViewHelper
        # the tag alias "myViewHelper" is later used in the view to access your service
        tags:
            - { name: templating.helper, alias: myViewHelper }
```

Now you can access the helper in a view like this:

```
echo $view['myViewHelper']->helpMe();
```